# Copy contents of one Array to another on OCAML

Tags: arrays, ocaml

I would like to replace the existing content of my array with a new Array.

Currently I have something like this

```
let orig_array = ref (Array.make 255 0) ;;

let do_something() = (

          .....
          let z = (*Some Array*)
          !orig_array =  z ;   (*THIS DOES NOT WORK*)  
  );;
```

Any suggestions on how i can replace my current array with the other array ? I know i could copy the elements one by one but I wanted to know if there was an easier way

Answer (score 1):

Your code has too many basic mistakes therefore I am not sure whay really you want.

If you want to copy the entire contents of an array and create a new one, simply use `Array.copy`.  `blit` is overly complex.

If you want to substitute the reference, use `orig_array := z`, not `!orig_array = z`.

In any way, you should go through OCaml tutorial carefully before writing some app...

Comment: Yes you are right. That was a silly mistake on my end. it was suppose to be `orig_array := z` apart from that what other mistake did you find. Thanks again for spotting this. Also is this the right approach when it comes to replacing an array with another one ?

Comment: You can keep the same array and give it new contents using `Array.copy`. You can make the reference refer to a different array using `:=`. It depends on which of the two you want to do. As a suggestion for learning OCaml, it's definitely worth trying not to overuse references. For arrays this is less illustrative because OCaml arrays are mutable. But it's still worth thinking about.